# Why do I always get the error "list" object has no attribute 'tranpose'?

Tags: python, matrix, attributes

This is my code:

```
class Matrix(object):
    """List of lists, where the lists are the rows of the matrix"""
    def __init__ (self, m=3,n=3,ma=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]):
        self.n_rows=m
        self.n_cols=n
        self.matrix=ma=list(ma)          

    def __repr__(self):
        """String representation of a Matrix"""
        output= "Matrix: \n{} \n Your matrix has \n {} columns \n {} rows"\
                .format(self.matrix, self.n_cols, self.n_rows)
        return output

    def transpose (self):
        """Transpose the Matrix: Make rows into columns and columns into rows"""
        ma_transpose=[] 
        for r in zip(*self.matrix):
            ma_transpose.append(list(r)) 
        return ma_transpose


    def matrixmult (self,other):
        """Matrix Multiplication of 2 Matrices"""
        m2=other.matrix
        ma2_t=m2.transpose()
        table=[]
        for r in self.matrix:
            row=[]
            for n in ma2_t:
                row.append(dot_mult(r,n)) 
                table.append(row)   into a list of row
                res=table
        return res
```

but each time I try to use the `matrixmult` function, i always get "the list object has no attribute matrixmult". Why is that? I have defined it earlier in the code no?

```
ma2_t=m2.transpose()
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'transpose'

Someone please help?

Comment: Take a look at `res`. What type is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line of `matrixmult()` is returning a `list`. It should return a `Matrix` object:

```
return Matrix(self.n_rows, other.n_cols, res)
```

Also in the `transpose` method, you should have:

```
return Matrix(self.n_cols, self.n_rows, ma_transpose)
```

Comment: aah, yes thanks ^^ it should be better that way. but do you know the problem with ma2_t=m2.transpose() part? :O how do i change the list into one that can use the transpose attribute?

Comment: You have to return a new instance of the Matrix class, with `n_rows` and `n_cols` swapped, since you transposed the matrix, and using `ma_transpose` as data. What you are currently doing, is returning just the `ma_transpose` list. I edited my answer. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.